# Plotly's subplot feature not working with Sankey diagram

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to plot a Sankey diagram next to a scatterplot but for some reason `plotly::subplot` is not rendering the charts correctly and I am unable to get any space between the charts. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong:

```
library(plotly)
plot_sankey <- plot_ly(
    type = "sankey",
    orientation = "h",
    node = list(
      label = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"),
      color = c("blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"),
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = list(
        color = "black",
        width = 0.5
      )
    ),
    link = list(
      source = c(0,1,0,2,3,3),
      target = c(2,3,3,4,4,5),
      value =  c(8,4,2,8,4,2)
    )
  )

plot_scatter <- plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~hp, type = "scatter", mode = "markers")

subplot(plot_sankey, plot_scatter, nrows = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a method that works, but I'm not sure why it's necessary. It seems as if the `sankey` doesn't respond to anything I designate for the layout as a subplot element. This method works, but you'll see an warning.

> Warning message: 
>     `layout` objects don't have these attributes: 'NA'

When creating the `sankey` designate the domain you want in the subplot. For example, if you wanted each plot to have the same amount of space with a .1 margin between them:

```
library(plotly)

(plot_sankey <- plot_ly(
  type = "sankey",
  domain = list(x = c(0, .45), y = c(0, 1)),  # <-- domain
  orientation = "h",
  node = list(
    label = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"),
    color = c("blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"),
    pad = 15,
    thickness = 20,
    line = list(
      color = "black",
      width = 0.5
    )
  ),
  link = list(
    source = c(0,1,0,2,3,3),
    target = c(2,3,3,4,4,5),
    value =  c(8,4,2,8,4,2)
  )
))

(plot_scatter <- plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~hp, 
                         type = "scatter", mode = "markers"))

subplot(plot_sankey, plot_scatter, nrows = 1, margin = .05)
```

This will look off center because only one of these has a legend. If it's important that they are even, you can add `showlegend = F` to the scatter plot.

[image]